# how to swap items in Dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary, swap

I have Dictionary like this

```
let test = ["first":1,"second":2,"third":3]
```

I want to swap first item  to the third item like this

```
let test = ["third":3,"second":2,"first":1]
```

how can I swap item?

Comment: Dictionaries don't have an order.

Comment: This is a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Please explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Are the 'first' and 'third' keys fixed? Or do you have access to their key-value before the operation?

Comment: Swapping is property of an array not the dictionary. In dictionary (key-value pair) you can just update the value by its key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionaries in Swift are an unordered collection type. The order in which the values will be returned cannot be determined.

You can use [`sorted(by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2298238-sorted) method to sort the dictionaries. The result type will be array of tuples.

```
let test = ["first":1,"second":2,"third":3]
//let result = test.sorted { $0.key > $1.key }
let result = test.sorted { item1, item2 in
    return item1.key > item2.key
}
print(result)//[(key: "third", value: 3), (key: "second", value: 2), (key: "first", value: 1)]
```

Comment: Even after sorting his purpose will not fulfil.

Comment: What about when you add `"fourth":4,  "fifth":5` to the dictionary?

Comment: @JamesP It depends how OP wants to sort the dict.  Changing `return item1.key > item2.key` to `return item1.value > item2.value` would work

Answer (score 6):

**Dictionary**

> A dictionary stores associations between keys of the same type and
> values of the same type in an collection with no defined ordering.

**NSDictionary**

> Dictionaries Collect Key-Value Pairs. Rather than simply maintaining
> an ordered or unordered collection of objects, an NSDictionary stores
> objects against given keys, which can then be used for retrieval.

So, answer is no. Dictionaries are used for fast retrievals, for ordering items you can use OrderedSet or apply your logic on array.